# GIT: Rename from "commit-graph.lock" to "commit-graph" failed. Should I try again?

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash

I am getting an error while performing a commit on GIT using GitBash. Somehow it is telling me that it is failing to rename a file "commit-graph.lock" to "commit-graph". And it even asks me if it should try again. I keep saying Y but the same message keeps coming back. It is a big commit with lots of files, I hope I am not going to lose the changes. How do I fix this? Here is what it is displaying:

[image]

Comment: Most likely another app or process has a lock on the file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I already looked at that answer and my situation is different. The folder is in a folder thet Git controls 100%. I answered 'N' to the question and it seemed to have committed my files, but what was the damage done? I don't know. I will see if I get this again the next time.

Comment: The linked question also shows that `commit-graph.lock` is under the `.git` subfolder which git controls. This does NOT block other apps from doing things to those files.